# Conflict of include files from an Arduino library

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm writing Arduino libraries and have the folder structure as follows:

```
libraries   
  +Foo
    -Foo.h
    -Helper.h   
  +Bar
    -Bar.h
    -Helper.h   
  +Helper
    -Helper.h
```

Foo and Bar are the libraries I created. The reasoning behind putting Helper.h in their folders is that, end user will have an easier time getting the libraries to work. Also, some libraries can only be configured by having their source code edited.

However, if I write `#include <Helper.h>` in my [sketch](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Sketch), it'll be impossible to control which "Helper.h" I'm including.

Is there a way to hide `Helper.h` from `Foo` and `Bar` from sketches?

Comment: Yes, do not add `Foo`, `Bar` or `Helper` to the include path, and include `Foo/Helper.h` and `Bar/Helper.h`. Or come up with names better than `Helper.h`.

Comment: @juanchopanza `Helper.h` is just a placeholder name, you can think about it as `Fat16.h` or something like that. Can you elaborate it a bit more and make it into an answer? Bit hard to understand here.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer is: don't write `#include <Helper.h>`.  Your
files aren't part of the implementation, and should be included
using `#include "Helper.h"`.  If you do this, the first place
the compiler will look for the include file is in the directory
containing the file which is including it: if you include it 
from `Foo/Foo.h`, the compiler will pick up `Foo/Helper.h`; if you include
it from `Bar/Bar.h`, the compiler will pick up `Bar/Helper'` and
so on.

Client code should only set the include path to the root, and do
things like `#include "Foo/Foo.h"`; if necessary, they can also
do `#include "Foo/Helper.h"`.

The one thing you do have to do with this strategy is to ensure
the uniqueness of all of the header guards.  If this is an
application, it will usually be sufficient to mangle the path
into the include guard, e.g. use `Foo_Helper_h`, instead of just
`Foo_h`.  Alternatively (and I would use this for any library
which third parties should use), generate some random string for
the include guard.  (If I open a file named `abc.h` which
doesn't exist, my editor automatically generates the following
boilerplate:

```
/********************************************************/
/*      File:       abc.h                               */
/*      Author:     J. Kanze                            */
/*      Date:       02/05/2013                          */
/* ---------------------------------------------------- */

#ifndef abc_h_20130502O481MBxFZeAzz4dgIb7iC4Q9
#define abc_h_20130502O481MBxFZeAzz4dgIb7iC4Q9

#endif
```

It's a safe bet that the include guard here will never conflict
with any other.  (And you have to do something along these lines
anyway, in order to get your copyright message in the file.)

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out a way that seemingly solves the problem:

```
libraries   
  +Foo
    -Foo.h
    +extra
      -Helper.h   
  +Bar
    -Bar.h
    +extra
      -Helper.h   
  +Helper
    -Helper.h
```

In this way, `Helper.h` in `Foo` and `Bar` would be invisible to clients, and I can write `#include "extra/Helper.h"` in `Foo` and `Bar` respectively to include the desired files.